# How to run intent in Libgdx (non UI ?) thread

Tags: android, libgdx

I googled some explanations but I don't understand them without exact example.
I would like to run the following code from Libgdx touchdown() thread.

```
       public void goToTheMarket() {
              Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
              .setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.myapp"));
       startActivity(goToMarket);
       }
```

The code has not compilation errors only in 
my "class MyActivity extends AndroidApplication".

It is visible as MyActivity.GoToTheMarket in Libgdx thread only as static.
But I got error that it is impossible to run static from non-static

If I create a class and run it as

```
       GoToTheMarket goToTheMarket=new GoToTheMarket()
```

then I got looper.prepare run time error.

Please write the full code how to run my code.
Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can take at [IntegratingAndroidNativeUiElements3TierProjectSetup](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/IntegratingAndroidNativeUiElements3TierProjectSetup)

It's a great guide to help integrate android native ui and libgdx.

Answer (score -1):

try below code.

context.startActivity();

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. To start which activity?  To create a new one or what? It needs intent. How the code should look? Thanks.